# What is the opposite of 'enrolled'?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

If I am displaying a list of courses that a person is enrolled on, the header for that list would be '*Enrolled Courses*'.

However, what would I put as the header for the list which contains those courses that they are not enrolled on?

Is '*Unenrolled Courses*' correct?

Is there an official word?

Comment: It depends on your meaning. Do you mean courses that they have never enrolled in at all (because there could be a very large number) or those that they *had* enrolled in but then dropped?

Comment: @JasonBassford it is those courses that they have not enrolled on, ever.

Comment: I'd say "available courses" covers the situation, even if it's not really an opposite.

Comment: The problem with *unenrolled*, although it is a valid adjective, is that some people might mistake it with *dropped*. In one sense, *rejected* or *overlooked* might work—but neither sounds quite right. (And what of courses that were taken in the past but which someone is not currently enrolled in?)

Comment: @JasonBassford ah, yes. I now notice how it can be perceived incorrectly. I never thought about it like that. Do you have any other alternatives other than those suggested?

Comment: So, let me ask this. For those courses that *were* taken, but are no longer being taken, do you want to list those in the second category?

Comment: @JasonBassford there may have been some confusion, the list consists of two items, those courses that are being taken and those that have *never* been taken (not even considered). There is no option to drop a course so I've not needed to worry about that list as of yet.

Comment: I had actually meant that you took course X last year and passed it. It's being offered again this year. But I understand now that you don't want it listed in the other category. What you're looking for is all courses that are "new to you." I will have to think about this. (At first thought, I can think of no single word to express it unambiguously.)

Comment: There are courses you have _completed_ in which you are not currently enrolled. Perhaps you want to list those.  There's another possible category: courses that have been or are being audited (not, therefore, for credit).  Then there are courses that you may need to take to complete a degree or course of study.  "Not enrolled" could cover all courses offered; you might as well deliver a catalog for the college or university.

Comment: Why is this list being shown to the user?  What decision do you want them to make?  If you want them to pick from the list in order to enroll, then “Available” seems ok as long as the list excludes courses that are full, and courses whose prerequisites have not been met.  Or maybe the list has been tailored based on the student’s major and the list is of “Suggested” courses.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the [naming](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of things like column headers is explicitly out of scope for EL&U.

Comment: To me, "unenrolled" suggests that they were previously enrolled, but have now decided not to pursue that course.  I would use "not enrolled".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Available Courses

By enrolling in a course (the first list), the person has effectively taken that course off the second list. You can't enroll in the same course twice, at least not without withdrawing from that course.

Comment: This doesn’t address the ambiguity in *available*: the set of courses available *from* the provider, those available *to* a specific student, and of those, the subset not yet taken. The OP only wants the third set, but “Available Courses” could mean either of the first two.

Comment: @Lawrence There is only ambiguity if the two lists are not for the person taking the course or someone advising that person in some capacity. The two lists aren't being created without purpose.  The op says, "I am displaying . . ." Whether the courses are from a provider's list, or a subset of that list, the displayer will know those courses are available. How could the displayer make that list without knowing that? The displayer simply wants a useful heading for information they already know.

Comment: @Lawrence Please note Jim's comment above, which I hadn't seen before.  As far as I knew "available" wasn't suggested (available seemed available), so I availed myself of it.

Comment: Hi Zan, on EL&U, 'naming' (selecting names for variables and the like) is off-topic, and I think this question illustrates why. "Available Courses" makes for a good label for the column in the context of the UI, but it's not particularly good as an *English* term to unambiguously mean "courses not yet taken".

Comment: As for crafting an answer around a term used in comments - that's acceptable on EL&U even if done intentionally. Comments are treated as ephemeral, and if the commenter had wanted to post it as an answer (with substantiation etc), they were free to do so.

Comment: @Lawrence So what should the question have been in order to elicit an answer that falls within the EL&U mission statement? You think that "courses not yet taken" is functionally an antonym for enrolled?

Comment: There's a checklist in the [tag:single-word-requests] tag information that helps with crafting such questions. The setting should be a sentence rather than a heading. E.g. *He enrolled in some courses but deliberately avoided [all others]*, as opposed to column headings "Courses Enrolled" & "Others". The repository we're contributing to is for questions related to the English language and its usage, so the question needs to be worded to suit. Viewing it another way: just because English words are used doesn't make it a question about the language. // On *courses not yet taken* - loosely, yes.

Comment: Should be isn't must be. If must be is meant then it must be changed to that. Loosely, yes. As an antonym for enrolled "courses not yet taken" poses the same problems you attached to available.